# Give a non-differentiable fixed-point function

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Give an example of a function $\phi:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ with unique fixed point $\phi(0)=0$, that is not differentiable at $x=0$ and where the fixed point iteration $\alpha_{j+1}=\phi(\alpha_j)$ for every $\alpha_1\in[-1,1]$ results in $\alpha_3=\phi^2(\alpha_1)=0$.
Could somebody help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
\phi(x)= \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
       0 & \mbox{if } x=0 \text{ or } x=1 \\
       1  & \mbox{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$